# How can I transform string sequence, which contains a list, into a list object?

Tags: python, string

I would like to know how to transform this string,

`"[{'id': 453, 'name': 'Paulo'}]"`

into a list, being the dictionary the first element of the list.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> 
>>> 
>>> literal_eval("[{'id': 453, 'name': 'Paulo'}]")
[{'id': 453, 'name': 'Paulo'}]
```

Comment: Why not just `eval`?

Comment: eval [isnt safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15197698/7540911)

Comment: `eval` is okay, but usually it's safer to use literal eval. This is explained nicely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34904657/5019169)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!